# Embedded React application to anthoer React application

Tags: reactjs, embed

I am a beginner on React but I have a complicated requirement on this. 
I have a requirement to embed a React application to existing React application. Embedded application may need to pass some value (e.g. id, password etc.) to existing application.

May I ask for any advice to reach this requirement?
May I have any example/sample project?

Thanks all!